# How I can save image in subfolder flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

**When I take photo it's save in default location "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures"  with my albumName. Suppose if my albumName is "TestAlbum" picture save in "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TestAlbum". It's work fine.**

**But I want to save my picture in "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Camera project/TestAlbum". How I can add "Camera project" folder under "Picture" folder.**

**I used "camera" package for capture image and "gallery_saver: ^2.3.2" for save image.**

***Code is here:***

```
CameraController? controller; 
     void _takePhoto(String folder) async {
        String folderName = folder;
        try {
          if (controller != null) {
            if (controller!.value.isInitialized) {
              image = await controller!.takePicture();
              try {
                await GallerySaver.saveImage(image!.path, albumName: folderName);
                print(image!.path);
              } catch (e) {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image not saved" + e.toString());
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e); //show error
        }
      }
```

Comment: Use path provider

Comment: can you share in details please.